# Адаптация сайта под мобильные устройства и плашеты

Tags: битрикс, html, php, css

Добрый день! Пишу Вам форумчане по такому поводу. Начальство поставило задачу адаптировать сайт под всевозможные мобильные устройства и планшеты. Стала задача разработки интерфейса под мобильные устройства. Так вот собственные вопросы:

1. Есть ли попроще классы на php типа
       MobileDetect которые позволяли бы
       различать с какого устройства зашел
       пользователь? Классификация по
       следующим типам: компьютер, телефон,
       планшет. Вдаваться в конкретные
       модификации телефона или планшета,
       не надо.
2. Есть ли бесплатные сервисы
       позволяющие шаблон сайта под ПК
       перевести под мобильное устройство с
       минимальными затратами?
3. Сайт разработан на 1с-Битриксе,
       соответственно шаблон под мобильные
       устройства будет подцепляться как
       альтернатива компьютерному шаблону.
       Где лучше прописать эти условия
       обработки типа юзерского устройства
       через которое он вышел на сайт?

Буду благодарен за ответы по всем или некоторым пунктам.

Comment: Тут я вам так скажу, конечно можно искать с какого устройства пришли и подкидать свой шаблон но лучше переводить шаблон в адаптивный. Нет смысла дописывать эти класы определяющие устройства и браузеры, лучше сообщить браузеру как при таких размерах окна сайт отображать. Для этого надо его переверстать. Если надо могу посоветовать верстальщика.

Comment: Ну не знаю мне сказали не переделывать сайт, а именно дописать логику сайта, если на него зашли с не компьютера. Для ПК сайт с фиксированной версткой, для мобильных надо резиновую верстку. А значит надо анализировать UserAgent (браузер) и устройство. Сам не верстальщик, а программист, потому и задал второй вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: Ваш битрикс на данный момент имеет возможность обновлений? В маркетплейс есть платформа для мобильных приложений. И она полностью бесплатна.

Comment: Да возможность обновления есть. @binliz, это хорошую мысль подали! Наверное надо двигаться в этом направлении.

Comment: @tlatypov, если мобильный и планшетный дизайн не подразумевает какого-то особого функционала на бекэнде, то я бы посоветовал всё делать на фронтенде через CSS Media Queries с дополнением на JS (там где css может не справиться). Посмотрите [очень показательный пример](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) как можно изменять сайт с помощью css (нужно сжимать экран браузера)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Есть ли попроще классы на php типа
> MobileDetect

Есть, но [найти их крайне сложно](http://mobiledetect.net/).

Comment: Ну а зачем мне ссылка на код MobileDetect? Может тогда кто своими исходниками поделится, как они различают ПК, телефон и планшет?

Comment: А посмотреть как работает MobileDetect и попытаться понять - не судьба? Тогда, боюсь, чьи-то ещё исходники вам не помогут... Тем более что они вряд ли будут работать как-то иначе.

Comment: Можно разобраться в чем угодно, если время есть. У меня времени лишнего нет на изучение дополнительных технологий, рабочий день расписан по минутам буквально. Просто общее впечатление от модуля MobileDetect слишком навороченный и бесполезный в плане различия мобильных устройств. Хотелось бы более легковесный код, который можно было вписать в компонент битрикса какой-нибудь.

Comment: Настолько занятым людям нужно не сюда писать, а на биржу фрилансеров. А были бы вы хоть чуть-чуть внимательней, то моментально бы обнаружили искомые методы. 
Впрочем, такая дискуссия заведомо бесполезная. Простите что не оправдал ожиданий.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ в любом случае). Придется в нерабочее время изучить этот MobileDetect дернуть оттуда может нужные методы.